# How to set a google map url dynamically from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I want to set a map url dynamically from code behind. e.g   gmap.Attributes.Add("src", branchurl);

Map.aspx.cs

```
protected void newLocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //retrieve the url from database & assign it to a variable "branchurl"
        gmap.Attributes.Add("src", branchurl);
    }
```

Map.aspx

```
<div class="mapbox" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <iframe id="gmap" runat="server" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/mapst=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=19.990933,73.760834&amp;spn=0.137443,0.154324&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried using gmap.Attributes.Add("src", branchurl); but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is you can create one property in code behind and then you can access that property in aspx using `<%=this.<propertyname>%>`

Ex:
in you code behind class i.e. in .cs file create

```
public String a="your URL";
```

in your .aspx access it like

```
<h1><%=this.a%> <h1>
```

Second Approach is using DataBinder

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(this, "a") %>
```

If you want dynmically set values to control properties in c#.

```
Ex:
protected void btSomeButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs ea){
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   btn.Text = "submit";
}
```

Reference Link For you: http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/347_Pass_Values_from_CodeBehind_to_JavaScript_and_From_JavaScript_to_CodeBehind_in_ASPNet.aspx